# echo -e "---\n..." for jekyll headers generates YAML exception

Tags: bash, echo, jekyll

I've written a script that automatically converts ipython notebooks to markdown and before the output is saved to file I add a Jekyll header by doing the following in bash:

`echo -e "---\ntitle: $title\n---\n\n$(cat $destfile)" > "$destfile"`

The problem is that whenever I add the Jekyll header, it generates a YAML exception:

`Error: YAML Exception reading notebook.md: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1`

The output looks like this when viewing with sublime, which looks exactly like an expected Jekyll header:

```
---
title: Built-in Data Iterators
---

### Note

Please view the README
```

As soon as I remove the header, Jekyll compiles just fine. If I manually create another Jekyll file with the exact same headers, it works just fine. What's going on here? Is this some sort of character encoding issue?

### Update

The same also happens when trying to use `printf`:

```
{
    printf "%s\n" "---"
    printf "%s\n" "title: ${title}"
    printf "%s\n" "---"
    printf "%s\n" "${output}"
} > "$destfile"
```

### Update2

Using the `file` command, it appears (for whatever reason) the output file is using `ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message didn't point to the correct line, but in one of my headers (not shown above) I was outputting a Jekyll variable such as `{{url}}`. Looks like they are not supported in the front matter. Removing this fixed the issue.